# why is the length of block after the block

Tags: binaryfiles

I'm extracting data from a binary file and see that the length of the binary data block comes after the block itself (the character chunks within the block have length first then 00 and then the information)

what is the purpose of the the block? is it for error checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of examples:

1. The length of block was unknown when write operation began. Consider audio stream from microphone which we want to write as single block. It is not feasible to buffer it in RAM because it may be huge. That's why after we received EOF, we append effective size of block to the file. (Alternative way would be to reserve couple of bytes for length field in the beginning of block and then, after EOF, to write length there. But this requires more IO.)
2. Database WALs (write-ahead logs) may use such scheme. Consider that user starts transaction and makes lots of changes. Every change is appended as single record (block) to WAL. If user decides to rollback transaction, it is easy now to go backwards and then to chop off all records which were added as part of transaction user wants to rollback.
3. It is common for binary files to carry two blocks of metainformation: one block in the beginning (e.g. creation date, hostname) and another one in the end (e.g. statistics and checksum). When application opens existing binary file, it first wants to load these two blocks to make decisions about memory allocation and the like. This is much easier to load last block if its length is stored in the very end of file rather then scanning file from the beginning.

Comment: Thank! I am dealing with a log file, I don't know whether or not the intention was to read starting from end, but it does make sense